# New table into Oracle db via SAS, lock table while writing

Tags: oracle, locking, odbc, sas

Can I lock for all access (including Oracle based queries) a table in an Oracle db via a SAS ODBC connection?

I am currently running a script in SAS which drops and replaces a table in an Oracle db via a ODBC SAS library.

My issue is that there are automated routines (running queries) which run independently of this script and I would like to deny them access to this particular table whilst it is being updated, to ensure that they do not run queries on the incomplete dataset.

Comment: Execte ddl command `lock table my_table in exclusive  mode`. This will prevent dml operations on the table. Remember to end the transaction with commit/rollback to release the lock.

Answer (score 2):

If the table has been dropped, then there is no way of tagging it as locked. In any case even an exclusive table lock will not prevent the table being read.

A better approach would probably be for the table to be accessed through a synonym, and instead of dropping it and recreating it, do this:

1. Create new table and load it.
2. Redefine synoynym to point to new table.
3. Wait for a couple of minutes
4. Drop the old table.